# Restricting the size of data structure being created

Tags: c, macros

My header file is

```
typedef struct vector vector;

vector * vector_create(size_t size);
```

The `c` file:

```
vector * vector_create(size_t size){
    if(size >= PTRDIFF_MAX)
        return NULL;
    //actual creation logic
}
```

I need to restrict the size of the `vector` to be no more than `PTRDIFF_MAX` since I need to subtract pointers to one vector element from the other. The problem comes when I want to test it

```
void test_create_vector_too_large(void){
#if SIZE_MAX >= PTRDIFF_MAX + 1
    list * lst = list_create(((size_t) PTRDIFF_MAX) + 1);
    assert(!lst);
#endif
}
```

This code produce tons of warnings

```
/home/kjroff/main.c:55:32: warning: integer overflow in preprocessor expression
 #if SIZE_MAX >= PTRDIFF_MAX + 1
                                ^
/home/kjroff/main.c:55:29: warning: the right operand of ">=" changes sign when promoted
 #if SIZE_MAX >= PTRDIFF_MAX + 1
```

The intention of the `#if` macro was to check if the upper limit of `ptrdiff_t` exceeds upper limit of `size_t`. In case they are the same this test does not make sense. But it does in case `PTRDIFF_MAX < SIZE_MAX`.

How to write such an assertion correctly?

Comment: Use a normal `if`?

Comment: Is this on POSIX?

Comment: Mathematicaly `#if SIZE_MAX >= PTRDIFF_MAX + 1` is the same as `#if SIZE_MAX > PTRDIFF_MAX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison is generally useless, as `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` are typically the same width but `size_t` is unsigned and `ptrdiff_t` is signed, so `SIZE_MAX` is necessarily greater than `PTRDIFF_MAX`. This is not strictly specified by the C standard, as `size_t` is merely the type used for size expressions and is, in spite of intent, not explicitly specified to be sufficient to represent the size of any object. Similarly, `ptrdiff_t` is merely the type used for differences of pointers and is, in spite of intent, not explicitly specified to be sufficient to represent the differences of all pointers.

That said, you can change the comparison to `SIZE_MAX > PTRDIFF_MAX`, which is equivalent, as pointed out by [pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg). Another way to quiet the warnings is to change `1` to `1u`, yielding `SIZE_MAX > PTRDIFF_MAX + 1u`. Per C 2018 6.10.1 4, in preprocessing, the integer types behave as if they were `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`, so `1u` has the type `uintmax_t`, so `PTRDIFF_MAX` will be converted to `uintmax_t`, then added to `1u` (which will not overflow), and the comparison will be between two `uintmax_t` types (avoiding a warning).

The question states “I need to restrict the size of the vector to be no more than PTRDIFF_MAX since I need to subtract pointers to one vector element from the other.” But the unit of a `size_t` is one byte, and the unit of a `ptrdiff_t` is one array element. Unless the `vector` type is a single byte, the result of subtracting two `vector *` pointers will be scaled down. Even in constrained systems where `size_t` struggles to cover all the possible sizes, `ptrdiff_t` should comfortably have room for the differences of two `vector *` pointers, regardless of the size of the underlying array. So the test `if(size >= PTRDIFF_MAX)` seems useless.

Comment: Consider the case if `vector` is defined as `struct vector { char *memory; size_t size; //other members }`. So the expression `((vector->memory + vector->size) - vector->memory)` does not yield UB only if I do the test `if(size >= PTRDIFF_MAX)`. Otherwise it might cause UB

Answer (score 2):

> How to write such an assertion correctly?

Instead of

```
#if SIZE_MAX >= PTRDIFF_MAX + 1
```

Subtract (`SIZE_MAX` is at least 65535) so no overflow possible.

```
#if SIZE_MAX - 1 >= PTRDIFF_MAX
```

or simply use `>` [@pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773517/restricting-the-size-of-data-structure-being-created/55775708#comment98219818_55773517)

```
#if SIZE_MAX > PTRDIFF_MAX
```